# Filter a 2D numpy array from an array of values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array with the following shape :

```
nonSortedNonFiltered=np.array([[9,8,5,4,6,7,1,2,3],[1,3,2,6,4,5,7,9,8]])
```

I want to :

**- Sort the array according to nonSortedNonFiltered[1]
 - Filter the array according to nonSortedNonFiltered[0] and an array of values**

I currently do the sorting with :

```
sortedNonFiltered=nonSortedNonFiltered[:,nonSortedNonFiltered[1].argsort()]
```

Which gives : `np.array([[9 5 8 6 7 4 1 3 2],[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]])`

Now I want to filter sortedNonFiltered from an array of values, for example :

```
sortedNonFiltered=np.array([[9 5 8 6 7 4 1 3 2],[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]])
listOfValues=np.array([8 6 5 2 1])
...Something here...

> np.array([5 8 6 1 2],[2 3 4 7 9]) #What I want to get in the end
```

Note : Each value in a column of my 2D array is exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to get a boolean mask and use it to filter columns in the sorted array, something like this -

```
output = sortedNonFiltered[:,np.in1d(sortedNonFiltered[0],listOfValues)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [76]: nonSortedNonFiltered
Out[76]: 
array([[9, 8, 5, 4, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8]])

In [77]: sortedNonFiltered
Out[77]: 
array([[9, 5, 8, 6, 7, 4, 1, 3, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [78]: listOfValues
Out[78]: array([8, 6, 5, 2, 1])

In [79]: sortedNonFiltered[:,np.in1d(sortedNonFiltered[0],listOfValues)]
Out[79]: 
array([[5, 8, 6, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 7, 9]])
```

Comment: wow that's perfect ! I was implementing a loop but it was way too slow for my huge number of values. This works way better

Comment: @OdgyGsf Yes, `np.in1d` is quite efficient to solve cases like this.